# Async Validation Redux Form Error Uncaught promise

Tags: reactjs, validation, asynchronous, axios, redux-form

I am trying to build a signup form using redux-form. I am trying to asynchronously validate if an email have been already taken.

If I enter a taken email, the input box becomes invalid (as expected), but when I enter an unique email and try to submit I run into the following error in console: "Uncaught (in promise) {email: "This email has already been taken"}"

Thanks!

```
//asyncValidate.js
import axios from 'axios';
const asyncValidate = (values)=>
{
    return axios.post('/api/emails',{email:values.email})
    .then(res => {
      if (res) {
        throw { email: "This email has already been taken."};
      }
    })
}
export default asyncValidate;

//route.js
app.post('/api/emails', (req, res)=>{
    User.findOne({email: req.body.email},(err,user)=>{
    if (err) {console.log("error");}
    else  {res.json(user)};
});
});

//SignUpForm.js
import {Grid } from 'semantic-ui-react';
import AccountFields from './AccountFields';
import ContactFields from './ContactFields';
import HistoryFields from './HistoryFields';
import WaiverFields from './WaiverFields';
import * as actions from '../../actions';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

 class SignUpForm extends Component {
    constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.nextPage = this.nextPage.bind(this)
    this.previousPage = this.previousPage.bind(this)
    this.state ={
        page:1
    }

}

nextPage(){
this.setState({ page:this.state.page + 1})
}

previousPage(){
this.setState({ page: this.state.page - 1 })
}


render(){
    const { onSubmit,submitForm, history } = this.props
    const { page } = this.state
    return(
        <div>
      <Grid textAlign='center' style={{ height: '1000px' }} verticalAlign='middle'>


            <Grid.Column style={{ maxWidth: 700 }} textAlign='left'>
                {page === 1 && <AccountFields onSubmit={this.nextPage}/>}
                        {page === 2 && (
                          <ContactFields
                            previousPage={this.previousPage}
                            onSubmit={this.nextPage}
                          />
                        )}
                        {page === 3 && (
                          <HistoryFields
                            previousPage={this.previousPage}
                            onSubmit={this.nextPage}
                          />
                        )}
                        {page === 4 && (
                            <WaiverFields
                                previousPage={this.previousPage}
                                onSubmit={(v)=>submitForm(v,history)}
                                />
                        )}

</Grid.Column>
</Grid>
</div>
export default connect(null,actions)(withRouter(SignUpForm));



//AccountFields.js
class AccountFields extends Component {

render(){
    const { handleSubmit} = this.props
    return(



<Form size='large' onSubmit={handleSubmit}>


  <Segment stacked>







      <Header as='h1' color='black' textAlign='left'>
          <Image src={icon1} />
      <Header.Content>
       Create your Account
       <Header.Subheader>     to make an online appointment</Header.Subheader>
      </Header.Content>
      </Header>



<Field
    name='email'
    label='E-mail'
    component={renderField}
    as={Form.Input}
    type='email'
    icon='user'
    iconPosition='left'
    placeholder='E-mail Address'
    />



      <Form.Group widths='2'>
          <Field
              name='password'
              label='Password'
              component={renderField}
              as={Form.Input}
              type='password'
              icon='lock'iconPosition='left'
              placeholder='Password'/>

              <Field
                  name='password1'
                  label='Confirm Password'
                  icon="lock" iconPosition='left'
                  component={renderField}
                  as={Form.Input}
                  type='password'

                  placeholder='Confirm Password'
                  />


      </Form.Group>
      <Button type='submit'style={{marginTop:'5px'}} color='black' floated='right'  compact size='large'>
            Next
          </Button>
          <Link to='/login' >
<Button style={{marginTop:'5px'}}color='black' basic floated='left'>Log In Instead </Button>
</Link>


    <br></br>
    <br></br>

  </Segment>
</Form>)}}



export default reduxForm({
  form: 'wizard', // <------ same form name
  destroyOnUnmount: false, // <------ preserve form data
  forceUnregisterOnUnmount: true, // <------ unregister fields on unmount
  validate,
  asyncValidate,
  asyncBlurFields: ['email']

})(AccountFields)
```

Comment: The problem seems to come from the `onSubmit` method, can you show us the code of this method ?

Comment: Hi @OlivierBoissé,  I have added the form file that contains the onSubmit method.

Comment: where does come from the `onSubmit` prop ? I don't see the call of the `reduxForm` function

Comment: @OlivierBoissé, I'm using the wizard form format https://redux-form.com/8.1.0/examples/wizard/

Comment: @OlivierBoissé, I added the part the account fields that is in the wizard form. I think that contains the reduxform function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you don't specify a response if your DB call doesn't find a user, the POST request will still receive a response from your route, though it'll probably be an error message saying that there was no response. In either case, your `.then` block will receive the response and so throw the error.

What you should do instead is have your POST handler return either an all-OK response if no user is found or an error message if the user already exists. If you use a 400 block HTTP response code if the user exists and a 200 if they don't then the error will go into a `.catch` block on your axios request and you can handle it there, whereas a success will go into the `.then` and you can do what you want there.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I have manage to get it to work with your advice!